# How do I get $form_state from hook_entity_update()?

Tags: forms, hooks, 8

I've manipulated the edit node form via `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` to insert a select pull-down menu.

In my module, I've implemented `hook_entity_update()` to fire when the edit node form is submitted. How do you get the form_state in `hook_entity_update()`? I want to save the user's choice from the select pull-down.

Answer (score 2):

$form_state is not available there.

You might want to consider using fields and widgets, then you get a lot for free.

If that's not an option then you can register a so called `#entity_builder`:

```
function menu_ui_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // ...
  $form['#entity_builders'][] = 'menu_ui_form_node_type_form_builder';
}

function menu_ui_form_node_type_form_builder($entity_type, NodeTypeInterface $type, &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $type->setThirdPartySetting('menu_ui', 'available_menus', array_values(array_filter($form_state->getValue('menu_options'))));
  $type->setThirdPartySetting('menu_ui', 'parent', $form_state->getValue('menu_parent'));
}
```

The example is for the node type config entity, but it should work pretty much the same way for a content entity. `book_form_node_form_alter()` is an example for nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've set up some code similar to what you described found in Drupal 8 core->menu_ui.module. If I understand it correctly, you insert a 'submit' type in the associative array and point it to a function that will have the form_state object. Thanks again.