# hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert never gets called

Tags: 8

Can anyone help me on the below functions. I am trying to alter user registration form and add my user form fields to default registration form. I am successfully retrieving data till validation, but I am not sure where I am going wrong in `hook_user_insert`. I am not able to retrieve the field value of my custom fields in hook_user_insert function.

Early support will be helpful in completion of the module.

```
function security_questions_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Hide the questions form when the user is being registered by an admin.
  if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('administer users')) {
    // Merge in our user form.
    $form += SecurityQuestionsUserForm::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'security_questions_form_user_register_form_validate');
    // We can't add our submit handler here, because the user account doesn't
    // exist yet. Instead, we will get the info during hook_user_insert().
  }
}

/**
 * Validation handler for security_questions_form_user_register_form_alter().
 */
function security_questions_form_user_register_form_validate(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  //module_load_include('inc', 'security_questions', 'security_questions.pages');
  SecurityQuestionsUserForm::validateForm($form, $form_state);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert().
 */
function security_questions_user_insert(\Drupal\user\UserInterface $account) {
  // During registration, save the user's answers.
  print_r($account->questions);
  die;
  if (!empty($account->questions)) {
    security_questions_user_answers_save($account, $account->questions);
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `die;` from your code.

Comment: ok I will remove it.

Comment: In Drupal 8 the user entity is fieldable, so you could simply add a field to the user entity and it will be saved automatically. If you don't want that and handle the field value in custom code then try an #entity_builders callback, which you can add in the form alter hook, to use it instead of hook_user_insert(). See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163821/how-do-i-get-form-state-from-hook-entity-update/

Comment: Is this a theme? Related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/262855/hook-entity-type-insert-never-called/262856

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a field to the user entity, which matches your form field key. Or, save the data in the session ..

Comment: I have added the form from another form by using alter, in D7 this is done using drupal_retrieve_form and passing form_state as reference. It works in D7 with hook_user_insert. For D8 even if I use entity it fails to get that particular field values from the form. How to do that?

Comment: If you cannot map the form fields to the entity fields, do it in form validate, by using $form['#entity'] to access the user entity.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Can I use the custom submit handler instead of hook_user_insert? I tried that is also not working. If you can rewrite my code form alter and send me it would be helpful.